# Add jss classname to array of jsx elements

Tags: material-ui, jsx, jss, css-in-js

```js
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles"

function styles() {
  return {
    item: {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li>{number}</li>
);
```

I want to be able to do `<li className={classes.item}>`. I want the each list item to get the color property from the item key in the styles object. Usually, the styles object is accessed by `withStyles(styles)` but how can I do this in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this in a lot of different ways. The simplest one I can think of is using a inline style tag like this:

```
class YourClass extends Component {
  render() {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return (
      {numbers.map(number =>
        <li style={{ color: "red" }}>{number}</li>
      )}
    );
  }
}
```

Or you could create a Theme like the API recommends [here](https://material-ui.com/style/color/) and use it like this:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    customColor: { main: red },
  },
});

class YourClass extends Component {
  render() {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {numbers.map(number =>
          <li style={{ color: theme.palette.customColor.main }}>{number}</li>
        )}
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```